# How to access the contents of an excel file stored in my model - django

Tags: python, django, excel, pandas, file

I am developing an app in Django.
I have a file model (let's say `my_file_model`) like this:

```
class my_file_model(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='myDirectory/', blank=False, null=False)
```

in which are stored excel sheets like this:

[image]

(fixed columns number, variable rows number)

And I have an empty model (let's say `output_model`) like this:

```
class output_model(models.Model):

    field_A=models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False)
    field_B=models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False)
    field_C=models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False)
```

I want to read line by line the data inside the excel file and save it inside my output_model,
so that I get something like this:

```
output_model:

    object 1:

        field_A: a
        field_B: b
        field_C: c

    object 2:

        field_A: d
        field_B: e
        field_C: f      

    object 3:

        field_A: g
        field_B: h
        field_C: i  

    ...
        ...
```

How can I do it?

Here is my script as far as I could write it:

```
def pour_entire_my_file_model():

    import pandas as pd
    from .models import my_file_model, output_model

    all_files = my_file_model.objects.all()  

    for file_element in all_files: 

        # I don't know how to access the excel file contents.

        for row in file_element:

            # I don't know how to access a certain excel file cell value of a file that is in my model.

            output_model.objects.create(field_A=cell(row,1)) # it's a
            output_model.objects.create(field_B=cell(row,2)) # it's b
            output_model.objects.create(field_C=cell(row,3)) # it's c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
def pour_entire__my_file_model():

    import pandas as pd
    from .models import my_file_model, output_model
    all_files = my_file_model.objects.all()

    for file_element in all_files: 

        excel_sheet = pd.read_excel(file_element.My_file_model)
        var_col_A = excel_sheet.Column_A
        var_col_B = excel_sheet.Column_B
        var_col_C = excel_sheet.Column_C

        for i in range(len(var_col_A)):            
            output_model.objects.create(field_A=var_col_A[i], field_B=var_col_B[i], field_C=var_col_C[i])
```